# Python Generic Exception Vs Specific Exceptions

Tags: python, exception

I'm writing a small production level Flask application that runs on IIS. I've wrapped all of my functions inside `try catch` blocks and it looks like this.

```
try:
     #Do Something  
except Exception,e:
     logger.error('Exception in Function X of type : %s ,for Image %s : %s'%(str(type(e)),path,str(e.args)))
```

I just need to log the problem in most of the cases and use python's builtin `logging` module to achieve this. I even log the type of the exception sometimes.

Now the thing I'm really concerned about is that although in my specific case, I don't have to handle or recover from any exception and even If I handle specific exceptions with a stack of different `except` cases, I'll just be logging the error in each block. So,

Is it still necessary for me to catch specific exceptions instead of
the generic `Exception`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is to log *all* exceptions, then no, you don't have to catch specific ones.

As you noted, there'd be no point as you'd only repeat the same piece of logging.